# JWT token does not begin with Bearer String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, jwt

I got a warning message like this "JWT token does not begin with Bearer String" before I generate the token, and it's also more warning like this when I open swagger.

[image: warning]

Comment: you have to add the string "Bearer" in the headers like this: `Authorization: Bearer eyJ........`

Comment: Can you add more details like the Authorization header you are sending?

Answer (score 3):

your have to provide the **Bearer** String,
must of the libraries out there provide and automatic way of doing that,
for example with `io.jsonwebtoken`

```
        long now = (new Date()).getTime();
String token = Jwts.builder()
                 .setSubject("username")
                 .claim("roles", "ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER")
                 .signWith(key, SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
                 .setExpiration(new Date(now + 86400))
                 .compact();
```

here **token** starts with **Bearer**